# Получение значений из dataLayer в GTM, не работает точечная нотация

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, gtm

После успешной отправки формы я записываю данные о событии в dataLayer с помощью след. скрипта:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, request, settings) {

   dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'ajaxSuccess',
          'ajaxSuccessData': {
            'url': settings.url || '',
            'data': settings.data || '',
            'responseText': request.responseText || ''
          }
        });
});
```

После тестовой отправки формы в дебагере GTM я вижу следующие данные:
https://yadi.sk/i/lxZrnWLwUamr9Q

Но как из массива data вытащить id формы и создать переменную уровня данных в GTM?
Конструкции вида ajaxSuccessData.data.0.1 не работают, скобочная нотация тоже.
Если создать переменную ajaxSuccessData.data, то в ней мы получаем список https://yadi.sk/i/5Bj9kBI7yWRbMA, но как вынуть оттуда данные в переменную не понимаю, это вообще реально?

Пробовал сделать объект data строкой, с помощью JSON.stringify() и toString() , но мой js на нуле, у меня это не сработало, переменная получалась пустой.

Comment: ajaxSuccessData.data[0][1]

Comment: комбинация точечной нотации и скобочной тоже не работает в данном случае

Comment: Ошибки в студию

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/7a3pgZQBMWjEeQ https://yadi.sk/i/ZbWr6bIwe5mZAw